# Does the minimum 256-byte SO_RCVBUF not allow a packet to be held?

Tags: linux, socket

`man mount`

> SO_RCVBUF
>
> Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes.  The kernel doubles this value (to allow space  for  bookkeeping  overhead)
>                 when  it  is  set  using  setsockopt(2),  and  this  doubled  value  is  returned by getsockopt(2).  The default value is set by the
>                 /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default file, and the maximum allowed value is set by the  /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max  file.   The  minimum
>                 (doubled) value for this option is 256.

but I think such a buffer can hold no packets

> [What values may Linux use for the default unix socket buffer size?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424380/what-values-may-linux-use-for-the-default-unix-socket-buffer-size/424381#424381)
>
> ...
>
> The per-packet overhead is a combination of struct sk_buff and struct skb_shared_info, so it depends on the exact size of these structures (rounded up slightly for alignment). E.g. in the 64-bit kernel above, the overhead is 576 bytes per packet.

Is the above correct?  Is there any good reason that the kernel enforces a minimum socket buffer size of 256?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at a previously-asked question ["What is the minimum SO_RCVBUF value?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970977/what-is-the-minimum-so-rcvbuf-value?rq=1) and [this network programming guide](https://notes.shichao.io/unp/ch7/#so_rcvbuf-and-so_sndbuf-socket-options), your suspicions seem correct. UDP and IP packets would get silently dropped because there would insufficient room to store the packet, and (from what I gather) TCP connections wouldn't work because the minimum transfer window size would be larger than the buffer; in any case, you wouldn't receive anything.

As to why the minimum socket buffer size is so small, that's probably a historical artifact in the documentation. Looking [at the Linux source v4.0 (linux/include/net/sock.h)](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/include/net/sock.h#L2015), it appears that the actual minimum size of quite a bit larger (2048+the aligned size of sk_buff) and has been [for quite some time](http://www.jauu.net/2010/08/08/linux-socket-minimum-receiver-buffer/). My guess as to why the documented minimum is so low is to allow for raw access to ATM cell packets, which were [48-53 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Transfer_Mode#Cell_size), but this merely a guess.